# IntelliJ JavaDoc @see

Tags: intellij-idea, syntax-highlighting, javadoc

I'm pretty new in IntelliJ.

My IntelliJ doesn't highlight the @see in comments. Looks like IntelliJ don't see @see as a JavaDoc keyword but I cannot figure out how to change that.

Is this normal or can I fix this problem?

[image]

Comment: Please show a doc comment which isn't highlighted as you expect

Comment: Ok I added a screenshot. I expected highlighting like @author

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is expected. `@see` is a block tag. It must be at the beginning of the line. See [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javadoc.html#blockandinlinetags)

> A tag is a special keyword within a documentation comment that the javadoc command processes. There are two kinds of tags: block tags, which appear as an @tag tag (also known as standalone tags), and inline tags, which appear within braces, as an {@tag} tag. **To be interpreted, a block tag must appear at the beginning of a line**, ignoring leading asterisks, white space, and the separator (/**). This means you can use the @ character elsewhere in the text and it will not be interpreted as the start of a tag.

(emphasis mine)

Your comment, if the goal is to generate a link to the `GlobalConstants` class, should be

```
Take a look at {@link GlobalConstants}
```

IntelliJ will generate that for you if you just type `GlobalConstants` and press Ctrl-space (or Cmd-Space).